# Change "response_type" from "token" to "code" using Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm creating an authorization via Facebook for server-side application.

Front-end should receive a "code"-parameter after user's successfully authentication and send this "code" to the back-end, which should call the Facebook API with it and receive an "accessToken" by itself.

The problem is that i'm currently using Facebook JavaScript SDK, which forms the URL (which will trigger login window) with "response_type=token" inside.

The question is: can i change it to "response_type=code" by passing some parameters, or so; and avoid using a "Manual build a Login Flow" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/)?

The code i'm using:

```
initializeFacebookSDK () {
   (function (d, s, id) {
      var js; var fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
      if (d.getElementById(id)) { return }
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      FB.init({
        appId: *some id here*,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v3.1'
      })
    }
}

facebookModalShow () {
    FB.login((response) => {
    console.trace({response})

    /*Request to the back-end with "code"-parameter in request body*/

  })
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: No, FB.login does not allow for that. It is meant for implementing the client-side login flow. But there is no real advantage in sending the code to the server - just pass on the access token you get from the client-side flow to the server, then you have all you need to make API calls from there.

Comment: @misorude so i'm not able to get "code" in the response using Facebook JavaScript SDK, right?

Comment: Yes, as I already said …

Comment: Thank you @misorude.

P.S. i was reasking because you've mentioned there: "...FB.login does not allow for that..." and i thought, maybe there are some different methods in the SDK (instead of FB.login()) for tasks like this.

Now it's clear.